# Equivalent of UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement in Silverlight 5

Tags: c#, pinvoke, silverlight-5.0

I'm trying to convert some pInvoke method calls to Silverlight 5 but have come up against a problem.How would I do the equivalent of calling UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement in Silverlight 5?

```
 public int Read(byte[] buffer, int index, int length)
    {
        var gch = GCHandle.Alloc(buffer);
        try
        {
             //Desktop .NET Framework code:              
             //var ptr = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(buffer, index);

             //WHAT IS THE SL 5 Equivalent here?

             //TODO Call some pinvoke code that requires 'ptr'

        }
        finally
        {
            gch.Free();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I'm reading UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement is just getting the memory address of an element in an array, why not just implement it yourself? You'll also avoid having to allocate the entire buffer a second time...

```
public int Read(byte[] buffer, int index, int length)
{
    unsafe
    {
        fixed(byte *ptr = buffer)
        {
            byte *ptr = ptr + index;
        }
    }
}
```